# Aggregation in C++: Date inside Class Article

Tags: c++, oop, aggregation

I have a problem with implementing Aggregation in my homework. We have to make a Class Article, get/set methods and private variables. I also have to use struct/class with a name Date (I inserted int day/month/year) and implement that struct type as Date ArticleDate in class Article as aggregation in private variables. I am explaining to myself that this ArticleDate should survive, even if I destroy the object of class Article. Is that right? + Will other objects of class Article and various subclasses be able to use it?
Could I get a good explanation, please? Thank you.
Here is the code:
Article.h

```
struct Datum { // struct is in the same header file as class Article (Oglas is Article in Slovenian)
        int dan;
        int mesec;
        int leto ;
};

class Oglas {
    protected:
        string naslov_oglasa; // title of Article
        Datum* datumObjave; // aggregation?
        double cena; // price
    public:

    Oglas();
    Oglas(const Oglas& t);
    ~Oglas();
...
};
```

methods.cpp:

```
Oglas::Oglas(): naslov_oglasa(""), cena(0)  {
    this->agregacija();
}

Oglas::Oglas(const Oglas& t): cena(t.cena), naslov_oglasa(t.naslov_oglasa) {
    datumObjave = t.datumObjave; //datumobjave = date of posting the article
}

void Oglas::agregacija() {
    datumObjave = new Datum();
    datumObjave->dan = 5; //day
    datumObjave->mesec = 11; //month
    datumObjave->leto = 1995; // year
}


Oglas::~Oglas() {}
```

Comment: Oglas is the Article?

Comment: @gsamaras in slovenian language

Comment: Ok Thanks, good question for a starter, you got my upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it, that you are using `Date` and `Article`, in English, to refer to the `Datum` and `Oglass` classes in your code.

Your `Article` class does not have a `Date` class member. It has a pointer to a `Date` class member. The difference is key, and important.

If your `Article` class actually did have a `Date` class member, then it would get destroyed, of course, together with the instance of the `Article` class, when the `Article` class gets destroyed.

But the only thing that gets destroyed, in this case, is a pointer to a `Date` class. If, somewhere else, there's another pointer to the same class instance, it can still be used by the rest of the code.

But if there isn't another pointer to this `Date` class, you've just leaked memory, congratulations.

Here's some Google food for you: `RAII`. Search on it, and read the top result.

Comment: Sam, nice answer, +1, I would suggest you to link to that top result you see. It might be different "tomorrow".

Comment: I have complete faith in Google.

Comment: Google will give you the top result at the time you search. I remember myself reading old answers here in SO that prompted to the "top result" and mentioned read that part, but they were obviously talking about a different result................................................................but OK, I am pretty sure that if the future reader sees another result, it will be still good, since your query is *too general*. :)

Answer (score 0):

> I am explaining to myself that this ArticleDate should survive, even if I destroy the object of class Article. Is that right?

**NO**.

---

> Why?

Because it is allocated *dynamically*, thus it will be there (allocated in the memory), "forever", unless you de-allocate.

Even worse, it will be a memory leak that you will not be able to reach, since the pointer will be gone when the object is destroyed.

---

So, **always de-allocate the memory that you allocated dynamically**.